# I am trying to run docker-compose up -d on a Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose

Whenever I run this command, `docker-compose up -d`, I run into this error which I am unable to solve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>

    from compose.cli.main import main

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 24, in <module>

    from ..config import ConfigurationError

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 12, in <module>

    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import (

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonschema/exceptions.py", line 152, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=True)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 's'
```

Answer (score 1):

To run your docker-compose command you have to define a docker-compose.yml file and specify a service which will consume your Dockerfile. You cannot execute docker-compose up on a Dockerfile

Simple example of docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

The build option allow you to specify the context which your Dockerfile is present.

Here is a link to the documentation
[getting started](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)